# android Studio debubbing

Tags: android, android-studio, xdebug, material-design

I am learning material design with developers.android.com but I did exactly what the site said should be done for the card_view. I only get this error:

"No resource identifier found for attribute 'cardCornerRadius' in package 'com.google.example.test_app'"

This is my code I am using.

`

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#fff"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_textview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:elevation="5dp" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? 
Thanks up front.

Comment: Paste the whole XML file (or at least include the first few lines)